# issue with a closure, cannot modify the value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code, after the first setCount I am not able to return the new variable update, what is wrong? thanks

```
const A = (() => {
  const operateState = <T>(initialValue: T): [T, (value: T) => void] => {
    let _value = initialValue;
    const setState = (newValue: T) => {
      _value = newValue;
    };
    return [_value, setState];
  };
  return {
    operateState,
  };
})();

console.clear()
const [count, setCount] = A.operateState(1);
console.log(count)
setCount(2)
console.log(count) // it should be 2
```

Comment: No, that’s not the way it works, count is a primitive. What are you trying to do?

Comment: do you mean it should be an object? I just learning more about closures

Comment: With object it would work: https://jsfiddle.net/79ye5k0w/

Comment: thanks, buy why does not work with primitives>?

Comment: Primitives are immutable

Comment: Because a primitives is copied by value, not reference.  IOW: count can't be changed by a function,..  Or better way of saying,  `_value` will change but `count` will not.

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: This doesn't have to do with *primitives*; the issue is that reassigning a variable doesn't affect other variables.  Code like `let y = expr1; let x = y; y = expr2` will have no effect whatsoever on `x`.  You can reassign `_value` all you want but `count` will never see it, whether or not `_value` and `count` hold primitives or objects.

Comment: @jcalz  I think the primitive reference here is comparing,  `x=1` to `object.x=1`,  changing `object.x` will have an effect because `object` is a reference type.  Indeed changing object itself won't have any effect, maybe the response should have explained the mutation of object part.. :)

Comment: I still don't understand how that has to do with primitives.  `1` is a primitive, but the difference between `x=1` and `obj.x=1` has nothing to do with the `1`.

Comment: @jcalz   `1` is a number, `number` is a primitive.  `object` is not a primitive.  I'm really unsure what point your making..

Comment: If this was written in the style of a solid reactive (as opposed to a react hook) - with the first value in the array being a getter - this would work just fine. But it’s still an absolutely ridiculous thing to try and write outside of the react (or solid) framework

Comment: @AdamJenkins   Solid's getter approach is indeed way better.  But not sure it's ridiculous to try an implement similar things outside of a framework, if not just for the learning experience.

Comment: @Keith But `x` is a variable, not a primitive, and whether the value it holds is primitive or an object is a red herring. I think we both agree that `x=a; y=x; x=b` won't let you get `b` from `y`, and `o.p=a; y=o; o.p=b` will. But this is true regardless of whether `a` and `b` are primitives or objects. You can demonstrate with `x=1` but you can also demonstrate with `x={z: 0}`. There's no reason at all to even mention "primitive" in the explanation, other than to make things more confusing. If that still doesn't make sense then maybe we should disengage since we're talking past each other.

Comment: @jcalz  In my first response I said -> `mutation of object part.`, so yes I do agree -> `x=a; y=x; x=b`  ,and the primitive part was that can't mutate a primitive, but you can an object.  IOW: storing `x` on an object, and using your getter/setter to mutate the object (that's not a primitive) was the point.  I mentioning it not been a primitive for storage, I'm unsure how that's not relevant, as it sure is.